# Model based on equations from literature

Tags: r, model, model-fitting

Firstly, I'm not very well versed in R. I want to compare my model to an already existing equation in literature.
My model looks as follows: `lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = train_df)`, and has been fitted to my data.
Preferably, I want to compare my model to an already existing model in the literature, which looks like the following: `y ~ a + bx1 + cx2 + dx3`.
How do I write down this known formula as a model without needing to fit any data?

I tried running the following code `Model <- lm(y - a ~ offset(bx1)+ offset(0.89*cx2) + offset (dx3), data = df)`, but this didn't work and resulted in new coefficients being fitted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to compare your fitted model to a fixed model with known coefficients a, b, c, and d from the literature. In this case, you don't need to fit another linear model. Instead, you can write a function that calculates the predicted values using the given coefficients and compare these predictions to your own model's predictions.

Here's an example using a fictional dataset and coefficients:

**1. Create a fictional dataset:**

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Create a fictional dataset
set.seed(123)
train_df <- tibble(
  x1 = rnorm(100),
  x2 = rnorm(100),
  x3 = rnorm(100),
  y = 3 - 2 * x1 + 0.5 * x2 + 1.5 * x3 + rnorm(100, sd = 0.5)
)
```

**2. Fit your model:**

```
# Fit your model
my_model <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = train_df)
```

**3. Write down the known formula as a function:**

```
# Replace a, b, c, and d with the known coefficients from the literature
a <- 1
b <- -1
c <- 0.9
d <- 1.4

known_model_function <- function(x1, x2, x3) {
  a + b * x1 + c * x2 + d * x3
}
```

**4. Calculate the predictions from both models and compare them:**

```
# Calculate predictions
train_df <- train_df %>%
  mutate(my_model_pred = predict(my_model),
         known_model_pred = known_model_function(x1, x2, x3))
```

**5. Plot the results:**

```
# Plot the results
ggplot(train_df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = my_model_pred, y = known_model_pred)) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = "dashed", color = "red") +
  labs(title = "Comparison of Predictions: My Model vs. Known Model",
       x = "My Model Predictions",
       y = "Known Model Predictions")
```

This will create a scatterplot comparing the predictions of your model and the known model from the literature. If the points fall close to the dashed line, it indicates that your model's predictions are similar to those of the known model.

In addition, you can use other metrics like Mean Squared Error (MSE) or Mean Absolute Error (MAE) to compare the performance of your model and the known model if you have a test dataset.

Comment: Use the offset function in an on formula.

Comment: Thanks you so much for this elaborate answer!

Comment: How would I go about using the test dataset on the known model? I tried the predict function, but this doesn't work on functions.

Comment: You want to do the step 4, but with test_df. :) That means you call predict() for your model and known_model_function(x1, x2, x3) for known model.